# What is the reason behind waiting 48 hours to offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

What is the reason behind waiting for 48 hours to be able to offer a bounty for your question?

Sometimes you could face a critical problem which needs a solution right away. Suppose you have the following scenario:

You have scratched your head for days/weeks, and the deadline is today, so you decide to ask for help. The problem is tough and time is needed to write a full answer. There could be people out there who knows the solution, but in their mind perhaps for 25 reps it is not worth the hustle.

To fire those people up, bounty is a good thing. But unfortunately you have to wait 48 hours.

I just wanted to know if there are solid reasons behind it.

Comment: It's to encourage you to learn better time management skills.

Comment: doesn't really answer my question. But I guess if you have a diamond, people will upvote nevertheless.

Comment: Well duh - it's a comment. But seriously, if you had managed your time better and thought to ask your question earlier - because there's absolutely nothing wrong with asking a question any time - you wouldn't be seeing the 48 hours as a barrier.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3333/165773

Comment: @gnat, thank you for finding this for me.

Comment: @BoltClock Sometimes you could think you are on track and realize a major flaw too late. Even the top managers are not immune to this. Anyway, I was just putting forth a scenario for better understanding. And of course it is a comment. I have been around SO so long to miss that.

Comment: @BoltClock while your point is valid, often you only _find_ what the question _is_ once time is already short. You might be digging around for some time before understanding fully what you need to ask.

Comment: Maybe the bounty delay could be changed to 24 hours?  Most people (even programmers) bathe and sleep once during a 24 hour period, which gives time for shower thoughts.

Comment: Completely agree with this question, sometimes a programmer might have a urgent problem and why force them wait 48 hours to solicit more attention to their question?

Comment: @BoltClock What does time management have to do with the question? It should be possible to offer a bounty whenever because sometimes circumstances are unforseeable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you have to wait 48 hours to place a bounty is to give the community time to answer the question normally. A bounty changes the way things normally work, and can mess up the normal flow question/answering. This is good if a question isn't getting a proper answer, but it is better to wait and give the system time to do its work.

Comment: What about the times you _know_ the question does not have a simple answer and will require a detailed answer to be useful - possibly including non-trivial code and so on - and are pretty sure nobody is going to provide that without additional incentive? I've posted questions like that and been proved right... C++ questions get people loving to answer put "how do I do X with niche technology Y" rarely attract such enthusiasm :)

Comment: @John And what about times when you want to get an answer fast and you're having no problem to "pay" for it? An answer in three days may be simply too late.

Comment: Well then we get into the whole "I want to offer money bounties" issue which has been discussed many times...

Comment: Really? On a site which, from my experience, is typically always full of experts, answers come through within MINUTES. If something isn't answered within the hour, then I guess it means it's "hard" or requires the extra encouragement. I hate this limit, if it's not answered within the hour, allow a limit.

Comment: This answer is super vague. The answer "The reason you have to wait 48 hours to place a bounty is to give the community time to answer the question normally" kind of just re asks the same question. *Why* must we always preserve "normality", e.g., in the case of a fire we are willing to pay for?

Comment: There's another reason than allowing the community to answer normally. It's handling crap the normal way, by not having a bounty interfere with flagging, closing and deleting things not making the (really low) threshold for acceptability.

Comment: 48 hours does seem a bit excessive. As @MyDaftQuestions pointed out, simple questions get answered (or put on hold, marked as duplicate, etc) very quickly. Why not allow users to sacrifice some rep to speed the process along? Having a waiting period makes sense....but so far I haven't seen a justification for 48hrs over 24, or 12, or 6 or even 1...what is so great about two days?

Comment: If it gets shorter, some people will develop the reflex of putting a bounty on everything they ask immediately. It will make the bounty questions list grow considerably. Bounty questions are supposed the be rare compared to normal questions. And it won't be the case anymore if they allow instant bounty. I would go for at least 12 hours.

Comment: I get it, 48 hours to preserve normality, most users use the system “normally” and this preserves the behavior they expect. HOWEVER, I have 3k points, have put in my dues, have a question for an issue I ran into Friday, would like for it to at least have some answers by Monday, and now it is Sunday and only 18 people have looked at it. **What about allowing users to pay a 500 point fee to waive the 48 hour waiting period?**

Comment: "but it is better to wait and give the system time to do its work" - But bounty is part of the system. Your answer is invalid. You act like a bounty would not cost anything for the person who pays it. The given scenario by the OP is absolutely reasonable and I think this 2 day rule should be removed, it just led to frustration for so many people who seek for help in stressful situations that involve time pressure.

Comment: Has this changed? I asked a question 2 days ago, and I have > 50 rep but I don't see an option to add a bounty to a question I'm getting pretty desperate over.

Answer (score 4):

**There are no data** that I am aware of that suggests that a 48 hour delay (or any other delay, for that matter) is optimal. The statistics at the top of the page on SO (and all other SE sites that I checked) show that **the questions with bounties are a minor fraction of all questions**. This suggests that  removing the delay for all bounties, or for large bounties, or for bounties posted by users with at least X rep, will have little effect on the rest of the questions.

**The best way to answer this question is by doing experiments** to measure the positive and negative effects of varying the bounty delay. Without the data, this conversation is limited to the exchange of opinions and case studies (with limited *N*). Possible effects/metrics to measure:

- **Quality of the bountied questions and answers**: question score, answer score, top answer score, % questions with accepted answers, % questions with no answers).
- **Percent questions voted to close or flagged** (as off topic, as very low quality, for moderator intervention).
- **Number of views per question for non-bountied questions** (to measure the degree to which attention is drained from non-bountied questions to bountied ones).

**FAQs:**

> An experiment would take a lot of work and risks introducing bugs. Why do it?

The current system uses a somewhat arbitrary delay of 48 hours for all users. Until these 2 days pass, all questions are considered equal in the sense that answering any of them, the rep per upvote/downvote and accepted answer is the same across all questions. **But all questions are not created equal!** Some are harder than others and would just sit there for 2 days doing nothing, because of the sheer effort required to answer them.

Comment: "the questions with bounties are a minor fraction of all questions" Isn't that the point? Bountied questions *should* be rare, or else there's little value to them. Also, [we already have a problem with people abusing bounties to keep their question from being closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399013/allow-bountied-questions-to-be-closed-by-regular-users), and removing the delay would just make that even easier.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, but even with your (valid) points, there are still no data... What we need is an experiment.

Comment: Consider when you vote whether it is better to have **data-driven** decisions, or...

Comment: I agree with this answer. People just _guess_ when they say that bounties mess up normal answers. It should be possible to give a bounty like whenever.

Comment: An experiment would take a lot of work and risks introducing bugs, so you need to provide a compelling argument for why it should be done. I don't see a real problem here except that people want answers faster, [which SO doesn't care about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: Bounty system should just be removed, along with all rep it ever rewarded

Comment: @KevinB What's the data to support your proposal?

Comment: Open the bountied questions list. Most of them are garbage

Comment: Do *what* experiment? What are the consequences that should be measured? Tweaking the bounty time is just the case, not the study.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your comment! I updated the answer with examples of experiments and metrics. I am basing some of the metrics on the concerns of the commenters above.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you think this is necessary.

Comment: @KevinB You are right. There are some poor quality questions among the bountied ones for sure. Full disclosure: I posted a bounty twice on my own question, and my own question can obviously be improved! I suggest that the effects on question quality can - and should - be measured experimentally, as a function of the bounty delay.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thank you for your comments and your suggestions! I think you raised valid points, which I have not consider before. I updated my answer. But I have to admit than my argument has become weaker... :)

Comment: *"because of the sheer effort required to answer them."* often stemming from the OP's inability to break their problem apart so they can realize it's just another dupe.

Comment: I don’t see how “hard question” equates to “just sit there”. The hard questions are often those most satisfying to answer.

Comment: _"There __is__ no data <...> that suggests that a 48 hour delay is optimal."_ Nor is there any data to suggest it's suboptimal. What is your point here? You post an answer to an ___old___ question, basically saying _"there is no data"_. Yes... and....?

Comment: @Cerbrus ...And I suggest to do experiments to get the data and to base policies on the data, not on opinions and case studies with low *N*.

Comment: that's actually a good experiment