# Editing older posts for bounty

Tags: support, edits, bounty, asking-questions

Is it acceptable to edit an older post to ask a new question and add bounty to it ? as new questions need time to add bounties.

I know this how it not supposed to work, but in reality you are not doing anything wrong IF the older post of yours is not really a good question and question you asked is of topic of less attention.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question a post asks, if it's asking the same question you want to ask you can of course add a bounty to it.

Comment: You should ask new questions as new questions. Do not edit old questions to change the scope of the question.

Comment: You probably should have asked us about this *before* doing it. Now you have wasted 300 reputation.

Comment: The OP mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22675133#22675133) that this was an "emergency," which [this other meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251739/what-is-the-reason-behind-waiting-48-hours-to-offer-a-bounty?rq=1) addresses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it is not acceptable to edit an older post into a different question to add a bounty to it. Doing that circumvents the rules of [how the bounty system works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

You should post a new question, then add a bounty if you don't receive an answer in the requisite amount of time.

Comment: Well, he already did it... and it was rolled back. Still has the bounty though.

Comment: @Deduplicator And?

Comment: Just wanted to mention it, in case that should be undone too.

Comment: He acted in a way to circumvent the way the bounty system works without first getting clarification. I would not refund his 300 reputation, IMO.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why should it be undone?  The bounty system is in place with rules for a reason, if the OP broke them, why should we reward them by refunding the bounty?

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: Well, depends on whether it was ignorance, wilful ignorance or malice (Remember panic makes stupid). And I just wasn't sure how far one should go in this case in presuming general good intentions. Quite likely my cynicism isn't properly engaged yet.

Comment: @bluefeet: I don't see how you're "rewarding" anyone by refunding the bounty. It's not like they end up with a positive increase in rep outside of any upvotes that they might have received - and there are no new undeleted answers yet.

Comment: It may have been complete ignorance or it may have been malice. In the grand scheme of things, 300 rep is a drop in the bucket and may not necessarily be "wasted" if it brings attention to the original question and they can award it to a quality answer. Either way, it does teach the OP not to act in haste in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock Rewarding isn't the correct term for it. Why refund it when they posted the bounty on a "new question" by circumventing the rules?

Comment: @bluefeet: I guess I don't mind treating it as though the OP meant to set a bounty on the original question. (And what's the deal lately with people on meta repeating things to me that I already understand and never asked about and those comments getting upvotes as though trying to make a point against me?)

Comment: I understand I made a mistake in haste, won't be doing it again, thanks for advise.