# Completely changing an old question so the user can put an instant bounty on it

Tags: discussion

The user edited an old question of theirs with no attention or answers in order to instantly place a bounty on it.

What's SO's view on this? Is it against the rules?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28557935/revisions

Comment: That is an invalid edit and should be rolled back (as I see you did).

Comment: Refer to the [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290196/editing-older-posts-for-bounty), as they posted it first.