# How do I offer an instant bounty to an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bounty, rules

In the last couple of months two things were happening regularly for which we don't have a provision on Stack Exchange.

- Received exciting answers and ideas to my posted questions.
- Received a lot of appreciations and accolades for the answers I provided.

In the first case, as a question asker I wanted to provide an instant bounty to the answer provider.

In the second case, the question asker wanted to shower an instant bounty on my answer.

So is there a provision for both the cases?

Comment: A more interesting question might be 'why would you not want to wait at least 24 hrs?  Why any rush?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as an instant bounty.

[The help page explaining bounties ("What is a bounty? How can I start one?")](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) explains:

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. **Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day.**

Similarly, [the page for the "Set Bounties" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) says,

> You must wait 24 hours before awarding a bounty.

Why is this? [This MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) gives an excellent explanation: (1) you might get an even better answer if the bounty is in place for a little while and (2) a waiting period helps prevent and expose abuse of the bounty system (moving points to friends, for example).

You should see these posts:

- [What is the reason behind waiting 48 hours to offer a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251739/what-is-the-reason-behind-waiting-48-hours-to-offer-a-bounty) (this is really about questions that do *not* have a good answer yet, and the waiting period has changed, but the reasoning hasn't)
- [I want to award a bounty to an existing answer; should I have to wait 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours)

Comment: If you already have received a brilliant answer, and want to simply say thanks through a bounty, the delay causes numerous problems: adds something to your 'to do' list, wastes legitimate bounty hunters' time clicking on the question /cluttering the bounty section, and (probably most importantly) waste's people's time who arrive at the question looking for answers - they particularly don't care about comments to the effect of 'thanks for the great answer, I'm awarding a bounty to you but have to wait 24 hours because stack overflow arbitrarily etc" that adds no value whatsoever to anyone