# Reduce bounty waiting period for higher ranked users

Tags: feature-request, bounty

We have to wait 2 days before we can place a bounty

As stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251739/what-is-the-reason-behind-waiting-48-hours-to-offer-a-bounty) "The reason you have to wait 48 hours to place a bounty is to give the community time to answer the question normally." but in my eyes it makes no difference if the question is asked normally or with a bounty.

but the timeframe where you actually receive answers is about 3-4 hours or less.

Users with a rank >= X (I recommend 5000) should be privileged to place bounties earlier, e.g. after 1 day or if the rank is even higher then after 6 hours. This will also motivate users to get a better rank if they know this.

Comment: What problem that *exists* is that solving? Because all I can think of are theoretical situations that seems too specific or a bit unrealistic.

Comment: @VLAZ I had that problem just last week, *knowing* it would take a bounty for people to look at my question and yet I had to wait 48h twiddling my thumbs over zero answer and zero comment and zero votes before I was allowed to place a bounty.

Answer (score 7):

Questions with bounties get their very own queue, guaranteeing extra attention for the bounty'd post.

That's basically the whole idea behind bounties. You pay for the extra visibility with some reputation.

Your statement that the first couple of hours are when the question's most visible *is* accurate, but that's not where bounties help.

Bounties are for questions that *didn't* get enough attention in the first few hours.
For questions that can be answered, but just require that one inquisitive mind to go digging for it.

Bounties are your lifeboat if the normal flow doesn't work. You don't get into your lifeboat while the ship is still chugging along.

Comment: I don't ask to be able to immediately place a bounty, but to be privileged to ask them earlier (1 day, half day...) than normally, if you are higher ranked.

Comment: I've had some questions answered after a day, though.

Comment: I also had questions answered after a week or two, but thats too late. Sometimes you just need a fast answer for a urgent task.

Comment: @Black: How urgent the question is really isn't relevant to SO, though.

Comment: then why do bounties even exist?

Comment: @Black: Because people want to pay rep to get more visibility for the question. The more people see the question, the more likely it is to get an answer. More difficult questions may even _need_ the rep incentive for users to invest time into answering them.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [this question about urgency on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: @Black if you want an issue to get fixed rapidly, hire someone and pay real money instead of paying bounties. I don't see why we should allow some users to have more power to make their question more visible.

Comment: I think after 24h it's pretty clear your question won't be answered. I see no harm in allowing high-rep members to put a bounty sooner. They still "pay" for it like anybody else. But as a high rep member, I *know* that I'll need a bounty for a specific question, but the system still makes me sit and wait for 48h without reply. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nvoigt, It is also clear after 12 hours.

Comment: So then why not 6 hours? Or 3? The timespan will always be an arbitrary value. It was set at 48 hours. If you need the problem fixed faster than that, pay someone.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm sorry to annoy you with this, but I do agree with the original question. Just to give you an idea: I've just started working at a new employer, whose system is based on Azure Devops. During my first day, I wanted to build the basic application, but in order to do this, some authentication was needed. As my professional GSM was not yet ready, I asked to do this by SMS, which did not work (too many SMS codes block the whole thing). I need to wait for two entire days just to build an application, while my reputation exceeds 8000 points. IMHO this is far too long.

Comment: @Dominique: If you need fast help, you're going to have to ask a colleague or pay a professional. The urgency you have in getting the question answered is completely irrelevant to SO.