# Using bounties to prevent question getting closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

I know similar questions have been answered before as to *why* close votes cannot be made on questions with a bounty. However, my question is whether it is OK for an author of a question, to apply a bounty on it, to prevent it from being closed and get some attention? Even, if it is of lower quality or there are issues with the question?

I've come across this question in particular: [Using Xamarin Forms Shell is it possible to implement Neumorphic tabs like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813552/using-xamarin-forms-shell-is-it-possible-to-implement-neumorphic-tabs-like-this) To me this question is of lower quality, because the author doesn't really seem to have invested any time into investigating what is already available and it appears to me they are seeking for a library, or some already finished solution to use. I don't see why this question is eligible for a bounty to begin with. Also,  this author in particular, seems to have done this a couple of times before.

Comment: [Until a proposed change dealing with bounties is implemented.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399013/allow-bountied-questions-to-be-closed-by-regular-users/399250#comment781509_399250)  The best solution to this problem is a custom moderator flag.

Comment: I guess custom flagging is an OK way to deal with it right now. Would be nice to give the community some more control, maybe at least people with some kind of track record. But I guess both links you provided answer this question.